# Convex function with lower bounds, is its minimum attained.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If a convex function is bounded below, can we say its minimum is always attained, i.e. there exists a $x$ that always satisfies the optimal condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This not true. Example :

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto e^x$$
is convex and has a lower bound but no minimum

However, it can be proved that if $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex and if $\lim_{-\infty}u=\lim_{+\infty}u=+\infty$, then $u$ has a minimum.